# char pointer value reassignment

Tags: c, pointers, char

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char *b,*a="a(a+b))";
    b=a;
    printf("%s",b);
    printf("%d",a);
    while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
        a++;
        i++;
    }
    *a="(a+b)";
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

initialy  i am assigning a value to that char pointer
after moving it to the end using null comparision
can i again assign a value to that char pointer?
Can i do like this? 
what is wrong here? can anyone please explain??

Comment: `*a="(a+b)"` - you can't do that (the third line from the bottom, the declaration is fine). Assigning `char*` to `char`. Also `a` points to a read-only memory.

Comment: You need to compile your program with warnings enabled. If you have a question about a specific warning, please ask here.

Comment: The code also has possible undefined behaviour because you increment *both* `a` and `i`, it is possible to skip over the 0 byte depending on the length of the string.

Comment: This question is too broad, since there's too much wrong in this code to give a short answer. Incorrect use of string literals, not understanding pointers, not understanding strings and string copy/assignment Also wrong printf specifier for printing a pointer, and the bug pointed out by Antti above. You are essentially asking for the whole chapters about arrays, pointers and strings in your beginner-level C programming book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your third line is failing is because youre trying to de-refrence and reassign a value to a "string" value on the stack. ( which is very very bad, please never do this if it ever lets you )

If you do want it to work, the compiler has to create a new string value and reassign the pointer so you would have to change the code to this.

```
a = "(a+b)";
```

This will create a new value on the stack and reassign the pointer to the beginning of that string.

However if you are going to use strings like that. PLEASE use const char *. Its ultimately safer and saves you a lot of headaches.